# cierre automatico de ventana tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

como puedo hacer para que la ventana tkinter se habra con un texto , luego se cierre automaticamente
desppues de un tiempo , cuando se abra la misma ventana otra vez con otro texto

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import  time

raiz0 = tk.Tk()     
raiz0.config(bg='silver', width='180', height='90')
frame0 = tk.Frame(raiz0)
frame0.place(x='0', y='0')
frame0.config(bg='silver', cursor='pirate',relief='ridge', width='180', height='90')

info = tk.Label(frame0 ,font=('Helvetica', 35, 'bold') , fg='red', bg='silver')
info.pack()

def funcion(texto):
    raiz0.mainloop()
    info.config(text=texto)
    time.sleep(5)
    raiz0.destroy()

funcion('hello')
funcion('by')
```

Answer (score 1):

En Tkinter es posible cerrar automáticamente ventana en cierto tiempo aunque como su problema se debe a intentar cerrar la ventana padre o raíz `Tk()` y volver abrir esa misma ventana, usted puede optar por crear una instancia de clase padre y llamar una función como un `Toplevel()` cada inicio, Si embargo retomando la cuestión, cabe resaltar que al cerrar la ventana padre y volverla a iniciar puede que sea complejo desde mi perspectiva ya que al crear una nueva instancia de clase de raíz `Tk()` dependerá en la rutina inicial o bucle `mainloop()` por lo cual su programa entonces no tendría que usar una rutina o ciclo inicial.

Con base en ello, mientras se ejecuta `root.destroy()` la rutina del archivo terminará y se destruirá la instancia de clase inicial ya que `root.mainloop()` se terminará al ser bucle o rutina principal del programa.

Posibles soluciones:

- Ejecute un bucle infinito al momento de llamar la ventana y en una
  función aparte ejecute el método `root.after()` para destruir la
  ventana sin terminar la ejecución del código. Usar `root.sleep()` deja inactiva la ventana hasta que se llame la función y no es
  recomendable ya que puede iniciar un *Thread*, otra subrutina o hilo
  dentro de la ejecución de la función lo cual puede congelar la ejecución del programa con tiempos prolongados, también usted puede intentar ejecutar otro código aparte que se encargue de iniciar determinada función.
- En vez de terminar la ejecución del código o dejar un bucle infinito, puede ocultar la ventana sin necesidad de finalizar la rutina o bucle principal y luego volver a llamar una función que restaure el estado visible de la ventana. Usando `root.withdraw()` para ocultar la ventana y `root.iconify()` para restaurar la visibilidad de la ventana.

Este es un ejemplo simple:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title('Esta ventana se va a cerrar...')


def MostrarVentana():
    root.iconify()
    root.deiconify()
    root.title('Ventana visible de nuevo') # Renombrar título de la ventana al volverla a iniciar.

def OcultarVentana():
    root.withdraw()
    root.after(3000, MostrarVentana)


root.after(3000, OcultarVentana) # Dentro de 3s más o menos inicia la función de eliminación u desaparición de la ventana
root.mainloop()
```

> Fíjese que `root.iconify()` requiere de un parámetro más el cual es `root.deiconify()` para que sea centralizada la ventana o restaurada y no esté minimizada en la barra de tareas. Este es el método más sencillo y rápido ya que en dos funciones obtiene el resultado y recalcando el cambio de título que se le da a la ventana como lo puede ver.